# Magento 2.2.9 problem after installing not loading some JS files

Tags: magento2, javascript

After successfully installing Magento 2.2.9 (Windows 10, wamp server) I got the following picture. Does someone know how to solve this?

I'm a beginner in Magento. I will be grateful for your answers.

[image: Magento 2.2.9 not loading some JS files]

Answer (score 0):

It might be caused by many things, I recommend change your base URL to use dev.local instead of localhost, then make sure that you are using developer mode and the generate all static files, you might be able to do all of this stuff running these commands below in your Magento root folder via terminal.

```
wget https://files.magerun.net/n98-magerun2.phar && chmod +x ./n98-magerun2.phar && alias n98="./n98-magerun2.phar"
n98 deploy:mode:set developer
n98 config:store:set web/unsecure/base_url http://dev.local/
n98 config:store:set web/secure/base_url http://dev.local/
n98 config:store:set web/cookie/cookie_domain dev.local
n98 dev:asset:clear
n98 generation:flush
composer install
n98 setup:upgrade
n98 setup:static-content:deploy -f
n98 setup:di:compile
n98 maintenance:disable
n98 i:reindex
n98 c:flush
```